# Is there a Google Calendar app for Mac desktop?

Tags: macos, applications, calendar, google

I want to know if there is a Google Calendar app for the Mac desktop? I do not want to sync my Google Calendar to my Apple calendar. I want to have the Google Calendar app itself on my Mac. Has Google made this?

Comment: [How to switch to Google Calendar](https://www.macworld.com/article/1157778/business-software/googlecal.html) show how to make a webkit browser app using [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Google haven’t made a desktop calendar app. You can add your Google account to Internet Accounts in macOS which will allow you to access your Google calendar in Calendar.app without syncing it with your iCloud account. Alternatively you can use [Fantastical](https://flexibits.com/fantastical) which also supports Google Calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [WebCatalog macOS app](https://getwebcatalog.com). Create a new Google Calendar app, sign in as you normally would, and then in the Preferences select 'Remember last page visited' so you don't have to sign in again. I run a number of Google and other services like this as one-off apps.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Apple's own Calendar.app (nee iCal), there's also the aforementioned Fantastical as well as the excellent [BusyCal.](https://www.busymac.com/busycal/)  Neither will by default synch between different accounts.

[This Google Help article](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358?hl=en) may also provide some guidance.